# Failed `librocksdb-sys v0.10.0+7.9.2` on Fedora 39

Tags: fedora

Trying to compile my Rust project depending on `librocksdb-sys`. On macOS, I had to update `llvm`, on Arch, I had to downgrade `gcc` to version 12. But on Fedora, I cannot make this work. Installed `llvm`, `clang`, `gcc`. Nothing worked.

Anyone on Fedora 39 and running into the same issue?